# using !! symbol before the scope variable in ng-show what would represent this ( !! )symbol

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

what is the real meaning of using (!)before the scope variable in angularjs. 
ng-show="!!file". What would indicate if I use this symbol in angularjs ng-directives

Comment: It is the way to convert whatever to boolean value

Comment: okay. can i use single ! symbol

Comment: Of course, you can

Comment: you saved my time. simple and concise answer i got from u @SlavaUtesinov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!!` is used as a shorthand for converting values to an explicit boolean value.

If `file` is "truthy", `!!file` will be `true`. If it's "falsy", `!!file` will be `false`.

```js
var nonEmptyString = "nonempty string";
var emptyString = "";

console.log(!!nonEmptyString);
console.log(!!emptyString);
```

The use of `!!` in your example is extraneous and pointless because `ng-show` will take care of checking whether the value is "truthy" or "falsy".

Comment: Now, I got clarification about using ! symbol

Answer (score 1):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered  true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

The ! is just a "not", but it has the effect of changing any truthy value into a false boolean and any falsy value into a true boolean. When you bang-bang a variable, you are basically converting it into a <s>true</s> real boolean value based on it's truthy/falsy behavior. This is generally a good practice but isn't entirely necessary.

Comment: Woops, I meant a "real" boolean variable as opposed to implied. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

! is for reverse Boolean and !! double reverse Boolean, Please check here: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nonEmptyString = "nonempty string";
var emptyString = "";

console.log(!!nonEmptyString);
console.log(!!emptyString);
```